# Questions about UDP requests in SOCKS5

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2, socks

I have couple of questions about the UDP requests in SOCKS5. I've already read this paper https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928#section-7 and i'm trying to implement it in C++.

Questions:

1. Do i need to use the "UDP request header" in both sending and receiving?
2. Can i use something like "WSASendTo" from winsock2 to redirect packets trough the SOCKS5 server?

Comment: Please review the posting guidelines which specify you should keep your questions limited to a single issue.

Answer (score 3):

> Do i need to use the "UDP request header" in both sending and receiving?

Yes.  This is covered in the document section you linked to:

> A UDP-based client MUST send its datagrams to the UDP relay server at the UDP port indicated by BND.PORT in the reply to the UDP ASSOCIATE request.  If the selected authentication method provides encapsulation for the purposes of authenticity, integrity, and/or confidentiality, the datagram MUST be encapsulated using the appropriate encapsulation.  **Each UDP datagram carries a UDP request header with it**:
>
> ...
>
> When a UDP relay server decides to relay a UDP datagram, it does so silently, without any notification to the requesting client. Similarly, it will drop datagrams it cannot or will not relay.  **When a UDP relay server receives a reply datagram from a remote host, it MUST encapsulate that datagram using the above UDP request header**, and any authentication-method-dependent encapsulation.

That means that both UDP datagrams sent by you to the SOCKS relay, and UDP datagrams you receive from the SOCKS relay, carry the same header.

> Can i use something like "WSASendTo" from winsock2 to redirect packets trough the SOCKS5 server?

You can use `WSASendTo()` to *send* your own datagrams to the SOCKS relay, yes.

But, if by *redirect* you mean to make other applications' UDP sockets send/receive datagarms through the SOCKS relay without their knowledge, then no.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but do you know any place i could find an example of an C/C++ SOCKS5 client with UDP support?

Comment: There are plenty of open-source SOCKS proxies you can look at, just search around. But it is really not a difficult feature to implement. The client sends a `UDP ASSOCIATE` command over the TCP connection, the proxy opens a UDP listening port, and sends its details back to the TCP client. Then, any UDP datagram received from the client on that port needs to be forwarded to the target, and any datagram received from the target needs to be forwarded to the client. When the TCP connection is closed, the UDP port needs to be closed as well.

Comment: Hello! I've gotten my SOCKS5 client mostly working, but for some reason it only works with local SOCKS5 proxy server. I figured out that the problem was that the proxy server was reading data from 0.0.0.0, but with the right port. I do exactly as the standard says so what could be going wrong? (I'm a beginner in winsock/SOCKS5 so don't judge)

Comment: @Olli can't answer that without seeing your updated code. Please edit your original question to provide more details.

Comment: Sorry, my code is too large for stackoverflow so i made private github repositary and invited you so you can view my code. Beware that it is extremely early poc, so the code isn't clean yet. You should look into onet.cpp, Peer::Connect function.

Comment: Do you have time to check my code?

Comment: Nevermind, finally got it working. Thank you for the help anyways.